# how to do 2-D fft of a big matrix efficiently

Tags: matlab, matrix, fft, channel, dft

a 8000*8000 matrix (Channel Impulse Response) --> Ht

frequency domain :
Hf=F*Ht*F'
(F is DFT matrix --> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix )

the problem is it takes too much time to do so,is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If your computer has a GPU, you can convert your matrix into a `gpuArray` as described [here](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/distcomp/gpuarray.html)

Then all the computation will be processed by GPU fastly.